# Flip meaning of 'fn' function key - e.g. F5 by default, Mute-Sound media key only when 'fn' is pressed

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, bios

I don't know if it's the keyboard model or a change in the system. After moving from HP Zbook G3 with Debian 10 to Zbook G8 with Debian 11, the way the function keys on the laptop are used has been reversed. Before I could use F1 to F12 directly, which I use *a lot* throughout many applications. In the few cases where I want to change sound volume or screen brightness, I held down the 'fn' modifier key. Now the opposite is true, so I can barely use the F-keys while working in IntelliJ IDEA, for example, without breaking my left hand.

**Is there a simple way to flip the modifier usage for F-keys / media keys?** This is in Debian 11 with Gnome.

Comment: This is typically controlled by the BIOS and as far as I know, the OS has no control over this (or at least can only have control if the BIOS allows it).

Comment: https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c02035108 suggests a BIOS setting, but it's not clear to me whether this applies to the G8.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' hah, excellent, I will try that, and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gilles-so-stop-being-evil, the solution is to go into the BIOS. On this model, it's *Advanced* > *System Options* > *Launch Hotkeys without Fn Keypress* > *Disable*.

Please appreciate my Nokia phone photos.

[image: BIOS photo 1]

[image: BIOS photo 2]